# Find the Max element out of all the nested arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

im trying to print the max number out of all the nested arrays but so far i only managed to get the max number out of each array individually

would love to get some help and insigth as to what i was doing wrong
heres my code so far:

````
const arr = [ 
    [1,2,3,10,9],
    [4,5,6,8,7],
    [7,8,9,6,5]
]

function matMax(){
    for (const items of arr){
        let max = 0;
        for (const item of items){
            if(items>max){
                max = items
            }
        }
        console.log(max)
    }
}

matMax()```


i dont want to use math.max method
````

Comment: You're resetting your max value before iterating over every sub-array. And you're not actually iterating over the sub-arrays, you're iterating over the main array twice. And you're redefining a `const`.

Comment: The declaration ```let max = 0``` needs to be outside the loop (it's reset on every element).

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 10, 9],
  [4, 5, 6, 8, 7],
  [7, 8, 9, 6, 5]
]

function matMax() {
  for (const items of arr) {
    let max = 0;
    for (const item of items) {
      if (item > max) {
        max = item
      }
    }
    console.log(max)
  }
}

matMax()
```

Modify the internal loop. The internal loop should loop through the external items, and const defines a new variable item to compare max

[image]

If you want to obtain the maximum value in all arrays, you can define the outermost layer of the max variable

like this：

[image]